Add new key to globalKeyboardHook
I'm making a auto keybord-mouse recorder. I am recording mouse click coordinat and keypress to json file. then ı am reading to json and I get the job done on the program.
My question is I am using turkish keyboard and have different words like i,ı,ü,ş,ç,ğ,ö... ı want to add these to my program. I did not find any code like 0x8C. I examined macro recorder app and it saved like Keycode225, Keycode124..... how can ı add these to my enum VKeys metod
enter image description here


namespace GlobalLowLevelHooks
{
    /// Class for intercepting low level keyboard hooks
    public class KeyboardHook
    {
        /// Virtual Keys
        public enum VKeys
        {
            KEY_I = 0x49,       // I key
            KEY_J = 0x4A,       // J key
            KEY_K = 0x4B,       // K key
            KEY_L = 0x4C,       // L key
            KEY_M = 0x4D,       // M key
            KEY_N = 0x4E,       // N key
            KEY_O = 0x4F,       // O key
            KEY_P = 0x50,       // P key
        }




I solved.  OEM_2 = 0xBF,     OEM_3 = 0xC0, ı think these are changing from key to key. ı determined which one is which key in my keyboard. if anyone see this post should try
